# jquery autocomplete cancel on unfocus

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using jQuery Autocomplete in a Wordpress plugin. How can I cancel the ajax/autocomplete when unfocussing?
`$first_id` is passed by PHP and allows multiple instances.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){

  $("#'.$first_id.'").autocomplete({
    source: function(req, add){
      $.getJSON("'.site_url().'/wp-admin/admin.php?page=church_admin/index.php&action=get_people&callback=?", req,  function(data) {

        //create array for response objects
        var suggestions = [];

        //process response
        $.each(data, function(i, val){
          suggestions.push(val.name);
        });

        //pass array to callback
        add(suggestions);
      });

    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
      var terms = $("#'.$first_id.'").val().split(", ");
      // remove the current input
      terms.pop();
      console.log(terms);
      // add the selected item
      terms.push(ui.item.value);
      console.log(terms);
      // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
      terms.push("");
      this.value = terms.join(", ");
      $("#'.$first_id.'").val(this.value);
      return false;
    },
    minLength: 3,

  });
});
```

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? What do you mean by "cancel the ajax/autocomplete when unfocussing"?

Comment: The input field stays grey with a loading gif when the ajax script can't find anything and also if you move onto the next form field. I'd want that to stop!

Comment: "input field stays grey with a loading gif when the ajax script can't find anything" jQuery Autocomplete doesn't make the field grey or show a loading gif. Those must be in your own code, which isn't shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought autocomplete handled that for you automatically. The example implementation give at the [jQuery site](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) shows the autocomplete being closed when the focus is sent elsewhere.

Is it possible that you have some code blocking it from closing properly?

Anyway - you can call close on the autocomplete manually, but I would investigate what is happening in your code first.

```
$("#'.$first_id.'").on('blur', function(){
    $("#'.$first_id.'").autocomplete("close");
}
```

*EDIT*

From your comment it sounds like you are adding some extra css when the autocomplete it being shown. You can remove this when the autocomplete is closed by listening to the `close` event with either:

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
  close: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

or

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "autocompleteclose", function( event, ui ) {} );
```